# How to get move event using ReadDirectoryChanges api?

Tags: windows, events, move, readdirectorychangesw

ReadDirectoryChanges windows api does not give file/folder move events(It works with rename events though). Instead It gives deleted and added events. How do we differentiate this from a real delete and add event.

**edit:** Is there a unique property for a folder in windows that does not change when the folder moves within a drive?.

Comment: What's the difference between a move and a rename event?  I guess by move you mean a recursive copy to destination and delete from source, in which case the behavior you described is to be expected.

Comment: As far as I know you can't. You don't have enough context.

Comment: I needed to monitor and index the files in a drive.. If I can identify folder move some way, I can avoid reindexing all the files in the folder...

Comment: @Luke By move I meant what windows does when we drag and drop a folder into another.. When I tested, renaming and moving a big folder within a drive took the same time and I did not see any copying progress bar...

Comment: I don't know what Windows does, but it is quite possible that it is doing a copy + delete; in that case this would be the expected behavior.